# Fancybox 3 и последняя версия Nicescroll не работает прокрутка в модальном окне

Tags: fancybox

Не работает прокрутка в модальном окне, работает только если крутить колесико в не блока.

**NiceScroll** подключаю так, т.к. он не работает в мобильных устройствах:

```
function isTouchDevice(){
    return true == ("ontouchstart" in window || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
}
if(isTouchDevice()===true) {
    $("html, body").addClass("overflow");
}
else {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        cursoropacitymin: 1,
        scrollspeed: 100,
        mousescrollstep: 60
    });
}
```

**Fancybox 3** версии подключаю так:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    focus: false
});
```

Все это вставляю в `$(document).ready(function () {}`

Версия **jquery 1.12.4**, **migrate 1.4.1**

Может что-то есть чтобы использовать и **Fancybox 3** и **NiceScroll** вместе?

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение дал разработчик fancybox

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    afterLoad : function( instance, slide ) {
        slide.$slide.niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#FFF"});
    }
});
```

или так

```
$(document).on('afterLoad.fb', function( e, instance, slide ) {
    slide.$slide.niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#FFF"});
});
```